# Text from file to the end of 2d char array

Tags: c#, arrays, file, text, char

I'm trying to solve the problem, but I just can't find the answer.

It is required to read a names.txt file, consisting of 5 words. After that, needs to convert them into char and then put the **left side of the matrix and the bottom** (look picture down). Other empty spaces need to fill with symbol **"+"**.

I've tried many variations, but it doesn't display correctly.

Please help!

[image: Correct output example [PNG]!]

```
    String txtFromFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\source\names.txt");
    Console.WriteLine("Words from file:\n{0}", txtFromFile);

    int rows = 10;
    int column = 10;
    char[,] charArray = new char[rows, column];

    for (int a = 0; a < rows; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < column; b++)
        {
            charArray[a, b] = '+';
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0} ", charArray[a, b]));
        }
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Comment: In the text file, are all the words on the same line or each on their own line?

Comment: each on their own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are inexperienced with `Linq` her is a solution without using it.

```
int rows = 10;
int column = 10;
int lineCount = 0; //pointer variable to be used when padding lines with +
string emptyLine = ""; 
emptyLine = emptyLine.PadRight(column, '+'); //create empty line string
string[] lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\source\names.txt").ToArray(); //read all lines and store in a string array variable

//add lines with only +
for (int row = 0; row < rows - lines.Length; row++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(emptyLine);
}
//loop through all read lines and pad them
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    lines[lineCount] = lines[lineCount].Replace(line, line.PadRight(column, '+')); //pad the line and replace it in the collection
    Console.WriteLine(lines[lineCount]);
    lineCount++;
}
```

This solution uses `string` instead of `char[]`. However, if you need to get the array you can simply find it in the read lines collection by

```
char[] charArray = lines[i].ToCharArray();
```

for an arbitrary index `i` in the read lines collection.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in one Line,

```
using System.Linq;    

...

//Read all lines instead of reading all inputs in form of text.
//Note: Expecting all words should be are stored on different line. 
string[] txtFromFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\source\names.txt");

var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 10) //Iterate for 10 lines
       .Select(x => x < 5  // Check for line number
          ? new string('+', 10)   //If line is from 0..4, then print ++++++++++
          : txtFromFile[x-5].PadRight(10, '+') //else print word then pad it with ++
       );

 //Print the result
 Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h82d6t)

output:

```
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
++++++++++
DOG+++++++
SHEEP+++++
CHIMPANZEE
BREAVER+++
LION++++++
```

Comment: @William,  if this is the case then you just read entire text and split by `,`. Like `string[] txtFromFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\source\names.txt").Split(',')`;

Comment: @William, I am glad my solution works for you. If it works for you then please do not forget to accept it by clicking on green tick.

Comment: maybe you know how to do the same code, but only through char[,] array? I need to separate all letters.